# Read/write data from command line using PHP

Tags: php, unix, sockets, analyzer, spectral

I have a server (debian lenny), spectral analyzer and I have downloaded collection of source codes from [Steve Sharples's](http://optics.eee.nottingham.ac.uk/vxi11/) site. With these s. coudes I am able to connect to spectral analyzer - type command and get the responce.

For example:

```
my-atom:~/vxi11# ./vxi11_cmd 135.123.106.59
Input command or query ('q' to exit): *IDN?
```

and I get: `Rohde&Schwarz,FSV-7,102004/007,1.50 SP1`

Am I able to connect to this server, write command and read the responce using PHP? I was thinking about sockets, but I am not sure if the best choice.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks,
Petr

Answer (score 0):

You can execute external programs using [exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), [system](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php), or [proc_open](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

I would recommend proc_open, which allows you to set up pipes for stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Check out the proc_open link.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I quite like shell_exec this is exactly what i want. But the trouble is that I have two physical machines (first - app (server), second - analyzer) with different IPs.

How can connect from my xxx.xxx.xxx.234 to xxx.xxx.xxx.187 run the shell command, grab the data and send them.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to connect to the remote machine from php, I would recommend looking into using one of these execute methods with ssh and an identity file.  You can use ssh and an identity file to execute commands on a remote server without providing a password.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do like:

```
$result = `SOME_COMMAND_HERE`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine [shell_exec](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) with netcat:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('echo "TRAC? TRACE1" | netcat -q 1 135.123.106.59 5025');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Note the `-q 1` option, which causes netcat to wait for 1 second for the answer. You don't need this wait time on "set" commands. Also, `*IDN?` does not need the wait time, [but many other query commands do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22632061/netcat-drops-incoming-packets).

Using netcat for this connection is dangerously close to the bare metal. You might want to write a shell-script that catches common errors. You can then call that script with shell_exec instead.

The best way of course would be to take [Steve Sharples free library](http://optics.eee.nottingham.ac.uk/vxi11/) and modify his cmd example to suit your own needs.